# angular 11 custom elements in new angular app

Tags: angular, custom-element

I am able to build the angular element and using a raw HTML page use the created src perfectly fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="./custom-button-element.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <app-button name="WORKS!!!"></app-button>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I try this example in a angular application I get the following err:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/custom-button-element.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

I have in the ''app.module.ts'' created a schema:

```
 schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
```

and my ''app.component.html'' looks like the following:

```
<h1>Container...</h1>

<app-button name="Test"></app-button>
```

my angular app ''index.html'' looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Container</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="./custom-button-element.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like the error is telling you exactly what's wrong. You can't access the JS file on the Angular dev server. You could always place the JS file in the assets folder and point to that.

Comment: @WillAlexander yeah no idea why I did not think of that! seems to work now thanks!